# Calculation of Seeback coefficient on Transiesta

Tags: siesta, electronic-transport

From the paper [Improvements on non-equilibrium and transport Green function
techniques: The next-generation transiesta](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2016.09.022), and in particular in figure 10b, an I/V curve is reported. I understand that from this the Seeback coefficient can be extracted.

However, in this figure, a curve calculated with two electrodes at the same temperature (300K) is reported. As far as my understanding goes, the Seeback coefficient should be calculated at a gradient of T. Is my understanding wrong? Can someone shed light on specifically how the Seeback coefficient is extracted?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but have you got an answer from elsewhere over the last few months? Are you still actively in need of an answer to this particular question? Please update us!